# Ruby on Rails and Masonry problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, masonry

I'm having some troubles implementing Masonry in my RoR project.

I think I can explain it better with the current web page: http://sttorybox.herokuapp.com/

As you can see, if you open the page, masonry is working fine. But, for example, you go into a story individual page (you must be logged in-> user:test@test.com , pass:test), clicking on title in the box (first box, it was created by test user), and now click in the title of the page: STTORYBOX in the top bar masonry now is not working and I don't know why :/

Here is my JS code:

```
$(function() {
  var options = {
    itemSelector: ".item",
    isAnimated: true,
    layoutPriorities:{
      upperPosition: 1,
      shelfOrder: 1
    }
  }

  $container = $("#items").masonry(options);
});
```

I hope you guys can help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue, the problem was some behaviour of [turbolink](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks/) rails gem.

The solution was to add all my content as a anonymous function like that:

```
var content = function() {
    ... content ...
};
```

And later using turbolinks function page:load in order to execute my code again

```
$(document).on('page:load', content);
```

Also I had to add this regular jquery function to load my content too:

```
$(document).ready(content);
```

I hope this help some people.